# Setting "endorsed" dir in an embedded tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, maven-2, endorsed

I am creating a web application using Eclipse (3.4), and m2eclipse. I am using the **deploy** goal but often prefer to use the **run** goal for the use of the embedded tomcat in the maven tomcat plugin. I added the xalan jar to the **endorsed** dir as I had problems with the xalan that is in the **rt.jar**.
It works fine on deployment, but I can't find a way to define the endorsed dir in the embedded tomcat as well.

The best for me is to have any solution in the project level (**POM.xml**) so that any other developer can enjoy running the application on an embedded tomcat.

Any idea?
Thanks,

Ronen.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a solution per se, but I would avoid using the endorsed dir, and make my own jar with the xalan version you want, with the package rewritten. This is employed by many open source projects because of the clash with the shipped xalan. There is a tool for jar rewriting, but I have forgotten its name and my google-foo seems to be lacking...